# how to limit text width based on its upper widget length in flutter

Tags: flutter

Here i am making a listview that contains circle avtar containing icon and a text below it

like applist in android

but here i want to fix text width based on circle avatar..it means text should be divided into two row if its longer than circle avatar's circle...

**I want all text in same size..dont want to use fitted box as it spoils look..some in big font and some in small**

here is my code

```
 Map<String,dynamic> iconMap={
    'Cart':Icons.shop,
    'Dinner':Icons.dinner_dining,
    'Refresh':Icons.refresh,
    'Backup Data':Icons.backup,
    

  };
```

```
Container(
          height: 100,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: iconMap.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  //border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    child: Icon(iconMap.values.toList()[index]),
                    radius: 30,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 4,),
                  Center(child: Text(
                     iconMap.keys.toList()[index],
                  maxLines: 2,
                  ),

                  )
                ],),
              ),
            );

          }),
        )
```

this is what i am getting....seee 'Backup Data' its crossing length of circle avatar[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by wrapping it inside `Container` or `SizedBox` and giving it width same as the `CircleAvatar`, and if you want the text to be centered to `CircleAvatar` you can use `textAlign` property inside text else you are good to go.

```
Container(
 height: 120, // increased height to fit the text without overflow
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: iconMap.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            //border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                child: Icon(iconMap.values.toList()[index]),
                radius: 30,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 4,
              ),
              Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 60, // width same as dimeter of circular avatar.
                  child: Text(
                    iconMap.keys.toList()[index],
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

[image]

`Note:` I have increased the parent containers height in order to fit both lines of text else the text will overflow.

Comment: Gud but here its static...i want dynamic...dont want to give fixed width to sized box..is there any option get width of upper widtet...here circleavatar

Comment: Whatever radius you are going to assign to the `CircleAvatar`  don't assign it in hardcoded like you have done for now that is `radius:30` instead store it in a variable say `int x=30` and assign it to the `CircleAvatar` radius, `radius:x` and in sizedBox width make it something like `width:x*2` it will make sure the the width of sized box is always equals to the dimeter of `CircleAvatar`

Comment: if you are getting the radius of `CircleAvatar` from an `API` call or something and radius of each `CircleAvatar` can be different from other, if this is the case then please let me know I'll modify my answer.

Comment: You are right but actually i am failing to make u understood that guess ..there is no size mentioned for circle avatar...how to get it now?

Comment: See the very first thing is `CircleAvatar` and `SizedBox` are two different child of `Column` widget so you can't use the height or width of one child to another directly, But as you have wrapped this column inside a `Container` so you can give width to this container and that width will be applied for all the children of the column, currently `CircleAvatar` and `SizedBox`

Comment: Hi Ahmed..can u pls check this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962693/failing-to-set-value-while-using-providers-constructor-in-flutter